# Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ControllerName' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

In `app.js` I have:

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
})();
```

in `process.js`  which is included *after* `app.js` I have:

```
(function(){
    app.controller('ProcessController', ['$http', function($http){
        this.something = "Test"
    }]);
});
```

and in my `HTML` file I have a `div`

```
<html class="no-js" lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
...
   <div class="row" ng-controller="ProcessController">
```

This is throwing an error in my console:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ProcessController' is not a function, got undefined
```

I'm pretty new to angular and have never used multiple files like this before. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to put `var app = angular.module("myApp");` in the process.js before the `app.controller(...)`.

Comment: @ShaohaoLin shouldn't `app` be available from the file included before hand? The error isn't complaining that `app` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `angular.module("myApp")` inside other JS file & don't forget to call function which will make sense to have [**IIFE pattern**](https://github.com/shaohaolin/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/ch3.md#invoking-function-expressions-immediately), which will help you to make `ProcessController` controller available.

**Code**

```
(function(){
  angular.module("myApp")
    .controller('ProcessController', ['$http', function($http){
        this.something = "Test"
    }]);
})(); //<-- () function should get called to self execute it.
```

Comment: This was part of the problem... adding `var app = angular.module("myApp");` as @slackmart suggested was the second piece to the puzzle

Comment: @Deekor `angular.module("myApp")` should be there ideally.. why you want `var app = angular.module("myApp");` again there.? honestly I don't understand what else you wanted?

Comment: IIFE stands for Immediately Invoked Function Expression. For more information about IIFE, take a look of this repo: https://github.com/shaohaolin/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/ch3.md

Answer (score 2):

Change your `process.js` to:

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module("myApp");
    app.controller('ProcessController', ['$http', function($http){
        this.something = "Test"
    }]);
})();
```

Also consider to use the syntax: `ng-controller="ProcessController as process"` in order to have access to `this.something` varialble after in your template `{{ process.something }}`.

Comment: shouldn't `app` be available from the file included before hand? The error isn't complaining that `app` doesn't exist.

Comment: also I tried your answer and got the same error :-/

Comment: In app.js you're defining your module, then inside process.js you need to get the module definition in order to define your ProcessController. In other words: the angular.module function can be used as a setter (`angular.module('modName', [/* dependencies */]);` or as a getter (i.e. `angular.module('modName');`

Answer (score 1):

At the top of your app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.controllers']);
```

At the top of your processor.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp.controllers', []);
```

Comment: You should probably answer in a more detailed manner, like "You should add [what] [where] [in addition/instead of] [what you have now]"

Answer (score 0):

'use strict' ; Defines that JavaScript code should be executed in "strict mode".
so it needs declaration first then definition . So in case you have declared the module added in app.js & added js to the index.html but not injected in the mainApp module , you have chances for ngareq ControllerName is not a function or undefined.
Hope so it would help .